# How to tell if a repaired laptop power cord adapter is safe?

Tags: power

I bought my mom, who lives in India, a Panasonic toughbook CF-W8 a couple of years back. A few days back, due to some voltage fluctuations, her adapter/power cord blew out (along with a whole bunch or other stuff in the house). Her laptop is fine and she has used it a bit with whatever power it has remaining. I have bought a new adapter for her over ebay and it should reach her in 3-4 weeks. In the mean time my dad asked a friend of a friend to fix the adapter and now some random person has "fixed" the adapter.

Now I am a bit nervous about the state of the adaptor and have asked my mom not to use it since i don't want her to damage her laptop.

I was wondering if there is any way to test if the "fixed" adapter is safe for use? and also, I just want to confirm that it is indeed dangerous to actually try the adapter on the laptop since I have no idea if the person who fixed it knew what he was doing.

thanks,

Comment: The same way you'll check that the one over eBay is safe?

Comment: The tricky thing is that you have to get someone who brought the adaptor to a back alley electrician to get it fixed to see if its fixed properly. If he can explain *what* he replaced, its probably good enough. I'd ALMOST trust it if he can say why

Comment: @GrahamWager  oh no...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Buy a voltmeter.
- Turn the adapter around, read the ratings. It must be something like 18V, 12V, etc. The rating will be stated.
- Plug in your adapter to the wall socket, turn it on **but not connected** to the laptop.
- Measure the output voltage from the other end of the adapter. if it is close to what is stated [+ or - 0.5V] then you can plug in to the laptop. If there is a difference like + or - 5V, there is some fault.

Comment: Be very careful. With the right (wrong) kind of damage, mains voltage may be passing through, and that can kill.

Comment: @Fasih Khatib Thanks a lot. How do I transfer the question? Should I just create a new one there?

Comment: @Bob is right. You should be careful while dealing with mains. And I have flagged the post for moderator attention. They will move it or best is for you to create a new thread there.

Comment: Fasih, if you already flag it for migration, please don't tell the user to post a new question. We'd almost have migrated it and would end up with the same posts twice. Consequently I've closed this here now, sorry @Amatya.

Comment: @slhck oops... I already created a new one there. Thanks for all the help anyhow.

Comment: @slhck I saw that there was no move to electronics option so I flagged it for moderator attention. Sorry about that.

Comment: Yes yes, it's fine to flag it, but then please don't tell users to also ask there, because it just creates a little extra work :)